# Number of Terms in a Polynomial (4th Degree)

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of terms of $(x^3+5x^2-x+2)^4$, when like terms are added.

My approach to this uses stars and bars to get $****|||$, since there are $4$ groups.

$\binom{7}{3} = \frac{7\cdot6\cdot5}{6} = 35$

However, this is not the right answer.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: There are terms in $x^k$ where $k$ ranges from $12$ down to $0$.

Comment: It's wrong because a 3rd-degree polynomial, raised to the fourth power, is a 12th-degree polynomial.  The highest power of $x$ will be $(x^3)^4 = x^{12}$.  There can't possibly be an $x^{34}$ term, any more than $(1502)^4$ could possibly be as big as $100000000000000000000000000000000000$.

Comment: Thank you!!! Just out of curiosity though, when would the strategy I used be applicable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you multiply and simplify you are going to get a sum of coefficients multipled by distinct powers of $x$, you just want to know what powers of $x$ are possible, the largest is $12 (x^3x^3x^3x^3)$ and the smallest is $0 (2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2)$.

You just need to explain why all the ones in between $0$ and $12$ also happen.

Answer (score 0):

expanding the given sum we get
$${x}^{12}+20\,{x}^{11}+146\,{x}^{10}+448\,{x}^{9}+451\,{x}^{8}+136\,{x}
^{7}+930\,{x}^{6}-356\,{x}^{5}+673\,{x}^{4}-216\,{x}^{3}+184\,{x}^{2}-
32\,x+16
$$

Comment: That's nice to know, but I was supposed to solve this problem in 2 minutes or less.